# Selecting correct .Net Framework for basic WPF - NUGET package can't install

Tags: wpf, nuget-package, .net-framework-version

I have created my first WPF project and it is written in .NET framework 4.7.2

I have NO idea about the importance and functionality of this however I want to be able to install it in a few businesses with as little chance of them needing to install a new framework.  Perhaps that isn't important and I should just include it in the installer, but that is what I am not sure of.

I tried rolling back to 4.5 .NET however now one of my packages will not install on that framework.

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'FluentEmail.Mailgun 2.8.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does
> not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

If I do any framework lower than 4.7.2 I can't see to run this, however I can't find documentation referring to this needing a specific framework to run.

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful,
eg. Is the framework important for a basic WPF app not using any crazy tech, just a few API's and mainly data storage?
Can I force this package to install on an earlier based framework or is that going to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FluentEmail.Mailgun](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentEmail.Mailgun/) package targets .NET Standard 2.0 which you can see by expanding the *Dependencies* section at NuGet.org.

.NET Standard 2.0 is implemented by .NET Framework 4.6.1 and later which you read from the compatibility matrix in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

This basically means that you need to target *at least* 4.6.1 to be able to consume the package in your app.

There is a caveat though:

> While NuGet considers .NET Framework 4.6.1 as supporting .NET Standard 1.5 through 2.0, there are several issues with consuming .NET Standard libraries that were built for those versions from .NET Framework 4.6.1 projects. For .NET Framework projects that need to use such libraries, we recommend that you upgrade the project to target .NET Framework 4.7.2 or higher.

So if you are developing a new app, you are recommended to either target .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later or even better .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5.

If you want the full story of which versions that are officially supported on which operating systems, you should refer to the lifecycle FAQ in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework).

Targeting 4.5 doesn't make much sense since the support for it ended back in January 2016.

Comment: THanks @mm8 that answers all my questions :) 
I wanted to target an older framework as I didnt want people having to install the new one as it will confuse my petty users, but yes I believe I will do that so they are using a supported framework.
As for the .NET Standard, I did see that but completely misunderstood as a N00b.
I thought it meant from .NET 2.0 onwards.

Comment: @GlennAngel separate topic, but you can include a fairly lightweight .NET installer within your installer, and run it almost silently. That might be easier on your users.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs thanks so much, will do.  When you say lightweight.. which one? eg. just the normal net to install in silent mode?